# Filter Date only from getdate in TextBox in ASP

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, datetime, filter

I have this =>

```
txtDrvBdt.Text = Convert.ToString(DrvBirthDt);
```

It gives `06/04/1995 12:00:00 AM`

and I want only `06/04/1995`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove time from a date/time string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4357707/remove-time-from-a-date-time-string)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [ToShortDateString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/system.datetime.toshortdatestring(v=vs.110).aspx) method:-

```
txtDrvBdt.Text = DrvBirthDt.ToShortDateString();
```

Comment: @BrijeshSonagara Please accept correct answer to your questions. It is the correct way to behave and this way you will give appreciation back to people that put down effort into helping you.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the following code part

```
txtDrvBdt.Text = DrvBirthDt.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```